# does Lego make bricks with a stone, brick or concrete block design?

Tags: piece-information

Does Lego make the bricks with a stone, brick or concrete block finish on the sides?  I would like to use these for walls and buildings on a train layout. Thanks!

Answer (score 10):

As usual with LEGO, the best solution is often to make your own.

You can make quite impressive brick walls using tiles, like this (image from [Brickshelf](http://www.brickshelf.com/gallery/cre8ivejuan/Brick-Wall-Study/lego-brick-building-0.jpg)):

[image: Wall]

There is a tutorial for something similar [here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KBZoTS7B6ns).

A range of other techniques can be found in an article called [Avoiding the "Big Gray Wall" Syndrome](http://www.classic-castle.com/howto/articles/biggraywall.html)  at Classic-Castle.com. In fact, [Google LEGO castles](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=lego%20castles&hl=en&client=firefox-a&hs=d4N&tbo=d&rls=org.mozilla:en-GB:official&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ei=YEQHUejDI4qM0AXHjYCAAg&ved=0CAoQ_AUoAA&biw=1525&bih=639) for a great source of inspiration for stonework of all kinds. For example, check [this](http://www.flickr.com/photos/sirens-of-titan/7321738142/in/set-72157630014646256) and [this](http://www.flickr.com/photos/fianat/8313132547/) out.

Comment: Even when simply placed next to another, tiles give a great effect, thanks to the bezel. Check [this house](http://news.lugnet.com/announce/moc/?n=3926) for a basic example

Comment: The gaping and color of the "Bricks" give a good allusion that its looks like a Brick Wall.

Comment: Related: [How can I add additional detail to large walls?](http://bricks.stackexchange.com/questions/1397/how-can-i-add-additional-detail-to-large-walls)

Comment: That looks like the pieces that have knobs on the sides are used for the walls, then flat plates are placed on the knobs.

Answer (score 8):

There's this part, which has a brick pattern molded into the side:

[image]

http://brickset.com/parts/?part=4646577

Comment: Since the brick was produced (some time last year) it can be found almost everywhere, it's already appeared in many official LEGO sets and MOC's and it's getting [cheaper over time](http://www.bricklink.com/catalogPG.asp?P=98283&colorID=69)

Comment: They're fairly widely used in the 'Friends' series

Answer (score 6):

In short: Yes.

There are actually quite a lot varying in base colour and stone/brick design.
As mentioned by another poster, many are from the castle theme, but there are also interesting ones from Duplo which may help with your layout if you are trying to cover a large area as the Duplo blocks are larger.

Some examples are below, but for lots more take a look through [these items on Bricklink](http://www.bricklink.com/catalogList.asp?pg=1&q=wall&catLike=W).

[image: Brick 1 x 6 x 5 with Stone Wall Pattern]
[Brick 1 x 6 x 5 with Stone Wall Pattern](http://www.bricklink.com/catalogItem.asp?P=3754pb07)

[image: Panel 2 x 5 x 6 Wall with Red Bricks Scattered Pattern]
[Panel 2 x 5 x 6 Wall with Red Bricks Scattered Pattern](http://www.bricklink.com/catalogItem.asp?P=4444p06)

[image: Panel 2 x 5 x 6 Wall with Scattered Stones Dark Gray Pattern]
[Panel 2 x 5 x 6 Wall with Scattered Stones Dark Gray Pattern](http://www.bricklink.com/catalogItem.asp?P=4444p02)

[image: Panel 3 x 3 x 6 Corner Wall with Scattered Stones Light Gray Pattern]
[Panel 3 x 3 x 6 Corner Wall with Scattered Stones Light Gray Pattern](http://www.bricklink.com/catalogItem.asp?P=2345pb06)

[image: Duplo, Brick 2 x 2 with Stone Wall Pattern]
[Duplo, Brick 2 x 2 with Stone Wall Pattern](http://www.bricklink.com/catalogItem.asp?P=3437pb018)

[image: Duplo Building Wall 1 x 8 x 8 with Window Opening - Castle]
[Duplo Building Wall 1 x 8 x 8 with Window Opening - Castle](http://www.bricklink.com/catalogItem.asp?P=51697)

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure some of the [Castle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lego_Castle) series have tall pieces with some brick outlines...